# In PL/SQL I get the error "Reference to uninitialized collection"

Tags: plsql

My code is:

```
create or replace type DateTab is table of date;
```

```
declare
    type Famous_Dates is table of DateTab;
    v_data DateTab;
    v_nested Famous_Dates:=Famous_Dates();
begin
    for i in 1..5 loop
        v_data(i):=sysdate;
    end loop;

    v_data.delete(2);

    insert into v_nested
    values v_data;
end;
/
```

I get this error saying my v_nested variable is not initialized with a constructor, but it is.

I know there was a question like this on StackOverflow, but it didn't help me, as I have something else in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two things, as marked in code below:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type Famous_Dates is table of DateTab;
  3    v_data DateTab := datetab();              --> this
  4    v_nested Famous_Dates:=Famous_Dates();
  5  begin
  6    for i in 1..5 loop
  7      v_data.extend;                          --> this
  8      v_data(i):=sysdate;
  9    end loop;
 10    v_data.delete(2);
 11
 12    select v_data bulk collect into v_nested from dual;
 13  end;
 14  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I still want to insert v_data into v_nested, and it gives me the error "Table or view does not exist", reffering to v_nested. It is probbably still not initialized correctly.

Comment: That's because you aren't inserting into a table, but into a collection. See line #12 above.